# How to hide repeated content from search engines with CSS?

Tags: html, css, seo

I have a page structure for a website using fixed headers/footers around the main content. To keep things simpler for responsive design, I'm not using margins around the main content, I'm actually repeating the header/footer in the document - one in the fixed position, and once in the dynamic one. This means I don't need to worry about different heights on different devices.

However, I don't want the repeated content showing in search-engine results, so how can I hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't hide anything from search engines.

For **good practice**, you should consider getting back to only one header/footer.

How about duplicating the header and footer with **Javascript**? You could use the jQuery [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method for this purpose.

Most search engine don't execute Javascript for their **crawling**.

Comment: I suspect you may be right; I was hoping that by 2014 I'd be able to address layout issues in CSS without leaning on JS.

Comment: Why don't you keep only a fixed header?

Comment: With a fixed header, I need to specify a margin for the content. As the header will have a different height depending on the viewport width, that forces me into using JS to adjust display properties. I'm starting to think I should have the header display once in-line, then make it fixed & patch margins on page ready / resize.

Comment: You could also use `em` units, so you don't have to bother changing all propeties. If the content's `margin-top` and header's `height` are in `em` units, you can change both by altering the content's `font-size` property.

Comment: Accepting this answer, since although it isn't what I want to hear, it is reality. However, the margin-top/height fix doesn't work quite so well if narrow width causes content to wrap. Going quiet now as I think this conversation has the potential to become long and rambling, and too specific to my needs.